# ¿Que está fallando en mi codigo?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, insert

quiero saber que esta fallando en mi codigo, porque al insertar datos, me tira el echo del error, estoy tratando de publicar propiedades para un sitio web de inmobiliarias. Saludos

```
 <?php 



  $servername = "127.0.0.1";

  $username = "root";

  $password = "";

  $dbname = "santiago_casas";


  // Create connection
  $mysqli = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);





    //-------------------------------------//


    $titulo = $_POST['titulo'];

    $descripcion = $_POST['descripcion'];

    $operacion = $_POST['operacion'];

    $tipo = $_POST['tipo'];

    $habitaciones = $_POST['habitaciones'];

    $baños = $_POST['baños'];

    $metros = $_POST['metros'];

    $ubicacion = $_POST['ubicacion'];

    $precio = $_POST['precio'];

    $usuario = $_POST['usuario'];

    $inmobiliaria = $_POST['inmobiliaria'];

    $moneda = $_POST['moneda'];


    // Protejemos los datos contra inyecciones SQL


    $titulo = $mysqli->real_escape_string($titulo);

    $descripcion = $mysqli->real_escape_string($descripcion);

    $operacion = $mysqli->real_escape_string($operacion);

    $tipo = $mysqli->real_escape_string($tipo);

    $habitaciones = $mysqli->real_escape_string($habitaciones);

    $baños = $mysqli->real_escape_string($baños);

    $metros = $mysqli->real_escape_string($metros);

    $ubicacion = $mysqli->real_escape_string($ubicacion);

    $precio = $mysqli->real_escape_string($precio);

    $usuario = $mysqli->real_escape_string($usuario);

    $inmobiliaria = $mysqli->real_escape_string($inmobiliaria);

    $moneda = $mysqli->real_escape_string($moneda);

    // Termino la proteccion de datos contra Inyecciones SQL




    //Empezamos la consulta INSERT


    $sql = $mysqli->query("

        INSERT INTO propiedades (titulo,descripcion,operacion,tipo,habitaciones,baños,m2,ubicacion,precio,usuario,inmobiliaria,moneda) 

        VALUES ('$titulo', '$descripcion', '$operacion', '$tipo', '$habitaciones', '$baños', '$metros', '$ubicacion', '$precio', '$usuario', '$inmobiliaria', '$moneda')"
    );



    if ($sql) { 

        echo "Bienn";

    }else{

        echo "error";

    }


?>
```

Comment: Podrias usar msqli error. https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.error.php para mostrar el error. Utilizar die y mostrar el error.

Comment: @Caruso y como y donde lo pondria?

Comment: tratando de proteger tus consultas mejor usa sentencias preparadas, mysqli de forma nativa soporta este proceso, te recomiendo cambiarlo

Comment: @Aprendiz sisi gracias

Answer (score 2):

Primero verifica que la conexión se haga correctamente (Esto dejabajo de `$mysqli = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);`)

```
if ($msqli->connect_error) {
    die("Error de conexión: " . $mysqli->connect_error);
}
```

Luego sustituye este código

```
$sql = $mysqli->query("
        INSERT INTO propiedades (titulo,descripcion,operacion,tipo,habitaciones,baños,m2,ubicacion,precio,usuario,inmobiliaria,moneda) 
        VALUES ('$titulo', '$descripcion', '$operacion', '$tipo', '$habitaciones', '$baños', '$metros', '$ubicacion', '$precio', '$usuario', '$inmobiliaria', '$moneda')"
    );

    if ($sql) { 
        echo "Bienn";
    }else{
        echo "error";
    }
```

Por esto

```
sql = "INSERT INTO propiedades (titulo,descripcion,operacion,tipo,habitaciones,baños,m2,ubicacion,precio,usuario,inmobiliaria,moneda) 
            VALUES ('$titulo', '$descripcion', '$operacion', '$tipo', '$habitaciones', '$baños', '$metros', '$ubicacion', '$precio', '$usuario', '$inmobiliaria', '$moneda')"
    if ($mysqli->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        echo "Insertado correctamente";
    } else {
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $mysqli->error;
    }
```

Y si falla ya te va aparecer el mensaje de error y sabrás cual es el problema.

Comment: Comparar en tu if contra true está de más ya que la respuesta al ser booleana si es positiva por defecto será true

Comment: @Paulo44 Hola, ya lo solucioné, el problema estaba en que estaba insertando en columna baños con ñ y no tenia utf8. Gracias